# Getting E73: tag stack empty while enabling visual mode in vim and select words using arrow keys

Tags: vim

I am getting this **E73: tag stack empty** issue while trying to select words using arow keys in VIM visual mode.

I dont see the same issue when I use hjkl keys to move my cursor in visual mode.

It was working fine until I uninstalled oh-my-zsh and installed zim instead. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: In your shell, what do you get when you do `<C-v>` then `<Arrow>` for each direction? In Vim, enter insert mode and do the same. What do you get? It should look like `^[[A`.

Comment: Btw, stop using arrow keys.